# TypeError: _.includes is not a function, Angular Google Maps

Tags: angularjs, lodash, angular-google-maps

While integrating google maps using angular-google-maps 2.3.1 with lodash 4.3.0 (Custom Build) , I am getting this error.

From some links I got to know they have some issues in latest version but I am not able to find the exact reason behind this issue.

Comment: Is lodash for sure being loaded? Is it being loaded before angular-google-maps?

Comment: Yes, it is loaded before angular-google-maps

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash/4.3.0/dist/lodash.core.min.js

Comment: What happens when you type _ or _.includes in the console? Is something perhaps overriding the _ global variable?

Comment: @Vadim Sorry I didn't get you, where in console?

Comment: The developer tools console in your browser

Comment: Could you try downgrading lodash to 3.8.0?

Comment: Thank you @troig , changing the Lodash version to 3.8.0 worked perfectly. It seems changes made in latest lodash are not properly synchronized with latest version of angular google map javascript.

Comment: Glad to help @dilpesh_jain. I've posted the comment as an aswer, just in case you want to mark the question as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I post in a comment, I had the same problem and I solved it downgrading `lodash` until version `3.8.0`.

Not sure why version 4.x doesn't work properly at the moment.