# Angular Google Maps Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, maven, angular-google-maps

I am using Maven + npm to use Angular Google Maps. It was working fine until I upgraded all my dependencies to latest version including Angular to 1.5.8

I even tried including underscore as a dependency, but it doesn't seem to be working either.

**Inside main.js**

*var angularGoogleMaps = require('angular-google-maps');*

**In Package.json**

*"angular-google-maps":"^2.3.4"*

Please suggest me something. I have tried everything I could find on Google, but unable to solve this issue

Comment: have you added underscore-min.js script??

Comment: yeah, that's what I mentioned in the description. Tried adding the same with browserify as well

Comment: Are you using lodash too? If that's the case, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298931/typeerror-includes-is-not-a-function-angular-google-maps/35346876#35346876)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking answer to the problem I faced, here are my findings:

`Angular Google Maps 2.3.4` has some compatibility issue with latest `lodash version (tested with 4.15.0)`. Reverting back to `3.8.0` didn't help so I had to switch to `angular-google-maps 2.3.3` and it works fine with `4.13.1`.

A ticket for the same has been opened at Github, link: [_ coudn't be found](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1940?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container)